# how to call a feature file to generated a Get request , for each element in an ArrayList or JsonArray ( Created by Java function )

Tags: karate, scenarios

basically I want to achieve below result , where the list used in Examples: is dynamic

Scenario Outline:

- def ss = 'https:testingurl/'+ < spaceCode > + 'trailPath';

  Given url ss

  And header Authorization = autGetToken()

  When method get

  Then status 200

  Examples:

  ```
  | spaceCode |

  | space1|

  | spac2|

  | spaceAbc05|

  | space.o2|

  | spacesacc|

  | spacere |
  ```

So I created one.feture and tried to call it from other feature file

one.feature

Background:

- def ss = 'https:testingurl/'+ < spaceCode > + 'trailPath';

Scenario:  need to run this scenario for each member of the spaceList ArrayList /  JsonArray

```
Given url ss

And header Authorization = autGetToken()

When method get

Then status 200

* print response

* def count = response.value.length

* print count

* karate.set('total', karate.get('total') + karate.get('count') )

* print total
```

question

1. how to run above file for each element  of the "spaceList" which  is an Java ArrayList, i am creating this ArrayList by calling method getSpaceList()

i have tried to call it from other feature file like below

Method1

caller.feature

Background:

```
* def total = 0

* def helper = Java.type('shared.Helper')
```

Scenario Outline:  calling other feature file for each element of the spaceList Array

```
def result = call read('one.feature')
```

Examples:

```
  | spaceCode |

  | helper.getSpaceList() |
```

Method2
caller.feature

Background:

```
* def total = 0

* def helper = Java.type('shared.Helper')

* def spaceList = helper.getSpaceList()  // this returns around 20 different elements from a sql
```

Scenario Outline:  calling other feature file for each element of the spaceList Array

```
def result = call read('one.feature')
```

Examples:

```
  | spaceCode |

  | spaceList |
```

i have also tried karate.forEach and karate.setUp

Comment: sorry this is too many questions in one - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask just ask one question. note that you can edit questions on stack overflow. personally I think you are trying to do too much with karate without understanding the basics. I suggest you try to do things without java to start with

Comment: its just one question , sorry i confused you, basically the statement at the top is the question

Comment: actually i am struggling with formatting on this page so i was editing my question so many times, my main problem is   i cant hard code values in Examples as its a dynamic list fetched from DB

Comment: please read this part of the documentation. then come back and edit your question to be specific, I can't offer more help than that: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

Comment: hi Peter 1) my question is that I want to  run a feature file multiple times  for given url  2) part of  this url is dynamic 3) this dynamic part i read from DB, so as many values are there in the db i have to run this request that many times. how can i achieve this

Comment: pls look at top feature file it will run 5 times , BUT  the number of rows  is not fixed for me and  I have to fetch these from DB, for fetching this data from DB  i have written java method  , so how can i use the data fetched from DB in the Examples: rows, so that this feature runs all rows fetched from DB

Comment: did you read the documentation ?

Comment: yes i read , i read this also https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature.... sorry  cant figure out........ ,when i run my feature file with data read from DB ( my sql returns 32 rows)... it runs only once ..... instead of 1 call for each of the 32 rows,  my file makes 1  call  only, it appends all 32 values to the url and makes a single call...

Comment: okay I give up. DB and Java code is "out of scope" for karate :) my suggestion is you should work with someone who has experience with java (and reading the docs). if you really need help, follow this process (and follow the instructions precisely): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: :( ..actually my issue is not with Java or reading value from DB.. all that is working... i am also able to read data from CSV.... my issue/ query is can karate run a post call for each value of a JsonArray which i create at runtime ( by reading values from DB /Java method ).. actaully i have already spent  3 days before posting here .. does this work in karate or not that my question                                                                               Examples:
| testdataJsonarry |

Comment: I submitted an answer. of course karate can do a POST for each value of a Json Array. your questions don't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. Note how it will make two POST requests. Once you understand this, you should be able to do what you want.

```
Feature:

Scenario Outline:
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* request __row
* method post
* status 200

Examples:
| [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }] |
```

Comment: thanks Peter for your help and patience, the eg you shared works for me but when i do the following changes i get error -- 
 ReferenceError: "dataList" is not defined 

Feature:

Scenario Outline:

* def dataList = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }]

* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'

* request __row

* method post

* status 200

Examples:

| dataList |

Comment: @RateeBhatt I have nothing to add to all the comments I have made already to your question.